# Understanding Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Previously I have worked with bog standard PHP and have recently made the move over to Laravel. One thing I cannot grasp is SQL queries in Laravel Eloquent.

For instance I have a **roles** and a **users** table. The roles table contains **roles and IDs for each role**. The users table contains various user details as well as a **role_id to reference the role** of the user.

What I have tried in my **user model**

```
public function role()
{
    // return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id', 'role_id');
}
```

What I have tried in my **role model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'role_id', 'id');
}
```

Then in my **controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $var = User::find()->role->get();

    return view('article', 
        array(
        'var' => $var
        ));
}
```

But now how do I access the fields in both tables as I would in ordinary PHP? I would rather use standard SQL but am trying to properly learn this framework.

Any advice?

Comment: change to `hasOne('App\Role', 'role_id', 'id');`, but in fact you can just ommit the keys and eloquent will guess them right in your case.

Comment: Tell me what relation you want between role and user (1-1,1-n,n-n). I'll give u an example

Comment: I would use  `belongsTo('App\Role')` for the `role()` relation.
This is how a 1-to-many relationship is modelled on the _many_ side.

Comment: https://www.w3adda.com/laravel-tutorial/laravel-eloquent-orm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access table fields via eloquent model attributes.

If you have fields like `name`, `email` you can fetch them like

```
$user = User::find(1);

$name = $user->name;
$email = $user->email;

$roleName = $user->role->name;
```

Note that you do not really have to call `get()` method on relation. Accessing it will call it automatically.

Laravel docs are pretty helpful in this matter. [Laravel 5.2 Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) and [Laravel 5.2 Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

Try it with eager loading

```
$var = User::with('role')->find($userId)->get();
```

Comment: If I do it in this way and then use a foreach loop, if I have columns with the same name, how does it differentiate the two?